# MS Office Word - How can I add custom table/cell margins?

Tags: microsoft-word, office365, layout, line-spacing

I am trying to achieve the affect I have drawn up below (fig.1), I have seen it on many resumes before though haven't a clue how to achieve it. Being a web dev, I have tried finding options to add margins to a table (please let me know if there is a better way to space things out in word, other than a table) row or cell, but I have only found options that change margin/padding for all cells. (fig.2) shows a table with and without spacing between cells, though this option is only found under the *Table (tab) -> Options -> Allow spacing between cells*, which does not allow changing of just the top and bottom spacing.

[fig.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/biOLC.png)

[fig.2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rPAB4.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use tabs instead of a table. Assuming you're using a metric scale, A4 paper and portrait orientation; set a right-aligned tab at 7.5cm and a left-aligned tab at 8.25 cm. This will create a space gap between two blocks of text, in the middle of your page. Tab to first tab position and type year range, then tab to second tab position and type job title or employer name (or whatever you're putting next to years). Hit return to start new line and tab twice to add text under second block of text.

[fig1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lwUXt.png) shows paragraph marks

[fig2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZwRb7.png) paragraph marks hidden

For the dividing line you could insert a line shape and adjust the weight, as desired.

Answer (score 0):

Create the table

Select the Cell

Right Click on the selected Cell and choose Table Properties

Under Table Properties - Cell - Choose "Options"

Cell Margins - untick "Same as the whole table" and then drop the margin to 0cm for left and right.

This should drop the left margin to touching the line. And then you can manually move the line to do a fit like the image below. Manually move it to fit to that size.

Comment: This, unfortunately, does not adjust the spacing to allow a disconnect between the verticle border to sperate each side. Not the best at explaining things, so this picture might help: [Imgur Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DugCU.jpg)